# Navigation view height I have set to match_parent but it doesn't really match the parent at all

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

The navigation view height I have set to  match_parent but it doesn't really match the parent at all
Below is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content">
    </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moveimage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For the height of the navigationView, how do I make it to fit the whole screen

The screenshot is at below:

[image]

Comment: Relative layout doesn't have orientation attribute

Comment: @Yasharyan What is orientation attribute ?So what should I change?

Comment: You have 2 relative layouts. The first one has the line `android:orientation="vertical"`. Remove it. Note sure if this fixes anything but it is an incorrect practice.

Comment: @Yasharyan Have removed it, but its not fixes anything as you said

Comment: @TommyChong: What purpose you take second relative layout? Do you want to add in NavigationView?

Comment: @shweta nope, it is a chathead I found some problem, thus Im using app:header so i cannot set the layout_height

Answer (score 0):

> Try below may help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lytMain"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moveimage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```